# Alignment of td inside a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table which consists of many rows. Each row has header ad table data. When I hide one table data it removes the space but inside the row space is maintained. Any solution would be appreciated.

So far I have tried using css display but not successful.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- adding display none from jquery as table loads from server -->
      <th style="display:none">a</th>
      <td style="display:none">b</td>      
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Display none hides the element but the row has an empty space. Is there a way to realign all the tds so it doesnt show the space if hidden.

Comment: Might be better not do a `display: none` but just work with `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: You could just remove the content (or replace it with a non breaking space) instead of hiding the cell - if you need to show it again, put it in a data attribute on the cell

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visibility:hidden` as that preserves space for the element, even though it is hidden.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- adding display none from jquery as table loads from server -->
      <th style="visibility:hidden">a</th>
      <td style="visibility:hidden">b</td>      
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- adding display none from jquery as table loads from server -->
      <th style="visibility:hidden">a</th>
      <td style="visibility:hidden">b</td>      
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The space you see before  cd in the third row that is what I dont want and elements should align themselves with the spaces going in the end of the last row.

Comment: please provide a screenshot or something to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(
    function() {
      $('table tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(1)').hide();
      $('table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').hide();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>hide me</th>
      <td>hide me</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- adding display none from jquery as table loads from server -->
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>      
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('table tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(1)').hide();
    $('table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)').hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2</td>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>hide me</th>
      <td>hide me</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- adding display none from jquery as table loads from server -->
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <td>b</td>
      <th>c</th>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The space after c d should not be there in the row. Instead a b from the third row should move up and so on and the spaces should end up in the last row.